# How to move ASP.net identity to other context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext, asp.net-identity-2

Currently I have two DB Contexts, One which I created called `CompetentieContext`, and another used only by ASP.net's Identity framework called `ApplicationDBContext`.

I need to have both in the same context, but I don't know how to migrate my `CompetentieContext` to the `ApplicationDBContext` or vice-versa.

I need them in the same context because I need to link the GUID's of ASP.net users to a Table in my Database.

This is how my context class looks like:

```
public class CompetentieContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Werknemer> Werknemer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Competentie> Competentie { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompetentieWerknemer> CompetentieWerknemer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompetentieWerknemerDetail> CompetentieWerknemerDetail { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TagGroupTag> TagGroupTag { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TagGroup> TagGroup { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompetentieTag> CompetentieTag { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: first: this is an EF problem - second: you don't have to bring both to the same database/context in order to use the GUIDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a table called `WebUsers` (or something similar) in your own database. It should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WebUsers](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SomeColumnName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [FkSomethingInYourOwnDb] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [WebUserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    ...
  CONSTRAINT [PK_WebUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Note** the `[WebUserId]` column which maps to `[AspNetUsers]` primary key column.

Now after updating your EF model/context (this depends on which [approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134) you use), create an abstraction called something like `IWebUserContext` and it's implementation `HttpWebUserContext`:

```
public interface IWebUserContext
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public class HttpWebUserContext : IWebUserContext
{
    public string Id => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
}
```

Next you can create your own context abstraction, let's call this `ICompetentieUserContext`:

```
public interface ICompetentieUserContext
{
    WebUserModel CurrentUser { get; }
}
```

Where `WebUserModel` is the EF entity we just created.

The implementation for this abstraction is entirely up to you, since I don't know your application's architecture. But you could, for example, use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), to inject the `IWebUserContext` into `ICompetentieUserContext`'s implementation.

You could also inject the EF dbcontext directly into your implementation (although I'd prefer using some kind of [Repository](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/11/repository-pattern-done-right/) pattern), and map the current `WebUserContext`'s `Id` to the one in your database.

Comment: As for your DI container, I would recommend [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html). Also [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) might be helpful for your architecture?